# How to show each users' data based on their Google account - Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I'm currently building a to-do app on Android Studio. I'm facing an issue with my Firebase database. What I'm trying to do is, each user to have a unique id based on their google sign in, in order to see only their own data. Currently, on my app, everyone can see anyone's' tasks. On Firebase I'm using the Realtime Database, specifying it by one child of "Users" and another one of Task + a random number. Also, I've already added the google sign in button on the launch of my app.

Current Database:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6IjN.png)

Example of how my hierarchy wants to be:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zbwja.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comments, to get only the Task objects the correspond to a particular user, please use the following lines of code:

```
String userId = "User-13294";
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference tasksRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(userId).child("Tasks");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot taskSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String title = taskSnapshot.child("title").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", title);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
};
tasksRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Because `User-13294` has only one Task, the result in the logcat will be only one title:

```
Swimming
```